# Zooming InkCanvas inside a ScrollViewer cuts the canvas - UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, scrollviewer

When using an `InkCanvas` inside a `ScrollViewer` to zoom out (`ZoomFactor` < 1), the resulting `InkCanvas` gets scaled down within its container and cuts off the content that was out of view in normal zoom. One would expect that zooming out would reveal the content from the `InkCanvas` that was out of view.

I am using the code below.

```
<ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled">
    <Grid>
        <InkCanvas />
        <Canvas />
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I tried setting a larger width on the control so that it overflows the container, but this does not help. Interestingly, the `Canvas` contained within the `ScrollViewer` scales correctly and reveals the previously occluded content when zooming out.

The image below demonstrates the problem. Pink circles are on the `Canvas`, while the ink is on the `InkCanvas`. The `ScrollViewer` is zoomed out and the ink contained in the `InkCanvas` is cut off.

Can I get around this behavior?

[image: Effect image]

Comment: I try your code, but I could not repro your issue. if you draw the line in the `InkCanvas`, it will show all the content when ScrollViewer  zoom out.

Comment: Could you share your rero sample for us ?